# Covariance of two correlated random variables

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

Suppose we have random variables $A,B$ with variances $\sigma^2(a)$ and $\sigma^2(b)$, respectively. Let them have some correlation, i.e. $cor(A,B) = \rho$. Now I want to calculate $cov(A+B,A-B)$.

For this I used the following formula:
$$cov(aX+bY, cW + dV) = ac\sigma(X,W) + ad\sigma(X,V) + bc\sigma(Y,W) + bd\sigma(Y,V)$$
After substituting in $A,B$ where appropriate and letting $d=-1$, we get that $cov(A+B,A-B) = \sigma^2(a) - \sigma^2(b)$. I'm wondering whether this result is correct -- does the fact that $A,B$ are correlated with some $\rho$ matter at all?

Comment: Yes. No, as your computation shows. More generally, for vectors $u$ and $v$ in any inner product space, $\langle u+v,u-v\rangle=\|u\|^2-\|v\|^2$ does not depend on $\langle u,v\rangle$.

Comment: @Did Thank you for the clarification. I had not thought about this problem in terms of linear algebra. If you want to post that comment as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter. Repeating your argument above, we have
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\cov}{cov}
   \cov(A+B,A-B) = \cov(A,A)-\cov(A,B)+\cov(B,A)-\cov(B,B)
$$
and, since covariance i symmetric, so $\cov(A,B)=\cov(B,A)$, the correlation cancels.

Think about it this way: One way to construct correlated variables from independent ones, is the following. Let $X,Y,Z$ be independent random variables. Then define $A=X+Z$, $B=Y+Z$. Then calculate as above
$$
\cov(A+B,A-B)=\cov(X+Z+Y+Z,X+Z-Y-Z)=\cov(X+Y+2Z,X-Y)=\cov(X+Y,X-Y)
$$
so the "dependent part" $Z$ cancels. This is not in itself a proof, sinve not all dependent variables can be represented as above, but it shows what can happen. The "dependent part" cancels.